# Find the maximum value $LCM$ pair in the sequence where $LCM(a, b)$ means the smallest positive integer that is divisible by both.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, natural-numbers, euclidean-algorithm

**Problem Statement:**
Given a sequence $S$ of $N$ positive numbers, calculate the $\max\limits_{1 \le i < j \le n} LCM(a_i,a_j)$, where $LCM(a, b)$ is the smallest positive integer that is divisible by both $a$ and $b$.

**For Example:**
$S$ = `13 35 77`
Answer: `1001`

$S$ = `1 2 4 8 16 32`
Answer: `32`

$S$ = `12 9 1 8`
Answer: `72`

**Constraints:**
$2 \leq N \leq 10^{5}$
$1 \leq a_{i} \leq 10^{5}$
Sequence $S$ is not-necessarily sorted.

This problem was recently asked in one of the programming contests and I came up with a brute-force approach that has a time complexity (worst-case) of $O(N^{2}log(ab))$.

The idea behind the brute force approach was, generate all the ordered pairs of the given sequence $S$ and keep track of maximum LCM and in last print the largest LCM.

But as the size of the sequence increases, the algorithm will be slower, for e.g. when $N = 10^5$, the brute force approach will take $10^{10}$ computations to find the answer.

However, I was wondering, is there an efficient way of solving the problem?

**P.S.** Although the problem is related to programming, I thought that the actual solution was inherently math, so it was more reasonable to post it here, rather than, say, StackOverflow.

Comment: This question was already asked. However, do you know other information about the possible sequences? From you examples it seems that all elements are distinct, is it an assumption? If not, you could improve your search by removing all duplicate elements in linear time.

Comment: @RiccardoAllegrone I have searched for the question before asking but I didn't get anything.

Comment: @RiccardoAllegrone All the elements of the sequence are distinct.

Comment: Ok, are there bounds on the entries and/or on the length of sequences? For example, if entries are $\le 1000$ (and distinct) and you have a sequence with length $1000$, then you know that all numbers from $1$ to $1000$ are in the sequence, so in constant time you can return $999*1000$.

Comment: @RiccardoAllegrone I have added the constraints part of the problem statement.

Comment: Ok, so for example it is not true that if $N=10^5$ you need $10^{10}$ computations: since you know that all possible values are in the sequence, you can return the maximum possible LCM which is LCM($10^5,10^5-1$). If $N$ is given as input, then you return the output in constant time, otherwise you can find the length in linear time.

Comment: @RiccardoAllegrone Can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: It is a very trivial observation but you can go on from it. If $N$ is really equal to $10^5$ and you know that all the elements are distinct, then you know that all elements from $1$ to $10^5$ appear exactly one time. So there is also the pair with the maximum LCM possible, i.e. the pair $(10^5, 10^5-1)$.

Comment: So why did you write $a_i \le 10^5$?

Comment: @RiccardoAllegrone Sorry, I have updated it. If you want more clarifications you can refer to https://codeforces.com/contest/1285/problem/F

Comment: That problem *does* have $a_i \leq 10^5$, but also doesn't say that the elements are distinct.

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}$I don't have a proof that this always runs quickly, but heuristically and in tests this tends to find the answer within a few dozen operations (plus a sorting and deduplication step).

First, sort (ascending or descending, I'll use descending below) the input and remove duplicates.

Call the resulting list $a$ and let $n$ be its length. Initialize $ans$ to zero (it always contains the maximum lcm we've found so far). Iterate over $i$ from $0$ to $n - 1$ and $j$ from $i$ to $n - 1$. We'll end up skipping most of this, so it'll be much less than $O(n^2)$ (at least conjecturally).

If $a_i^2 \leq ans$, then for any $x, y \leq a_i$, $\lcm(x, y) \leq x * y \leq a_i^2 \leq ans$, so there's no point in continuing the iteration. Any other pair later in the iteration will have an lcm less than or equal to the maximum we've found, so we're done.

Similarly, if  $a_i * a_j \leq ans$, then for any $y \leq a_j$, $\lcm(a_i, y) \leq a_i * y \leq a_i * a_j \leq ans$. This means for the remaining $j$'s, the lcm will always be less than or equal to $ans$, so we can move to the next $i$.

If we haven't skipped to the next iteration, les $ans$ be the maximum of $ans$ and $\lcm(a_i, a_j)$.

Finally, once the iteration is finished (or we ended it early), $ans$ contains the result.

In pseudocode,

```
Input: a = list of positive integers

sort a descending
remove duplicates from a

ans = 0
for i from 0 to len(a) - 1

    if a[i] * a[i] <= ans
        break

    for j from i to len(a) - 1
        if a[i] * a[j] <= ans
            break
        ans = max(ans, lcm(a[i], a[j]))

return ans
```

In practice, for random lists following the constraints, I never iterated over more than a few dozen $(i, j)$ pairs before the program ended. The worst case I can think of is that the list is a sequence of prime powers, in which case we'll iterate over all the pairs of half the list. But with the bound on size, the worst case is with $\lfloor log_2(100,000) \rfloor = 16 $ different powers of $2$, so we'd only have $8 \cdot 9 / 2 = 36$ pairs to iterate over.

---

**Edit:** With less random inputs, this can have very poor performance. For example, even random inputs where all the $a_i$ are even will cause huge issues.

Comment: Can you look at the `python` code (https://pastebin.com/uZ8cDf5b) which I have written on the basis of the pseudocode which you provided? If the code is correct, then it's not giving the correct answer.

Comment: The loops should be nested. You have two separate loops for i and j, but the j loop should be inside the i loop.

Comment: Also, you're missing the dedup step, which can cause bad behavior if the list is all the same number, for example.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated it (https://pastebin.com/epQuDkaN), but still, the program is slow.

Comment: Slow with what inputs? As noted, it does pretty well with purely random inputs, but fails when the inputs are crafted to foil this exact approach.